# Azure AppService plans and Resource Groups

Tags: sql-server, azure, cloud

Im trying to get my head around proper design of my resources in Azure "universum".

I have done following as pre-reqs for future deployments
+ created Resource Group for SQL Server
+ Created SQL server

lets call it **RG-dev-SQL**

At the moment I have build myself deployment templates that kick of building of the following :
+ creates resource group RG-webapp-dev-someappName
+ creates AppService plans (1 basic / 1 shared) **AppSp-someappname-B1** | **AppSp-someappname-B1** 
+ creates webapp called **webapp-dev-someappname**
+ Uses one of the before created AppServicePlans for the new web App
+ performs deployment

This works - however my question is if this is the way to go - so using Resource groups lets say per application that I deploy ? So repeating the process above for example for App1...App33 ?

I'm interested how other people see this of use ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's totally up to you.
Advantage of having similar entities in same resource group gives you guarantee that all of those entities will run in the same region. So if you web site is using sql server you've created and you want to make sure response time will be minimum it's good to use same resource group.
I'd say that if you plan to use multiple services and combine their functionalities, it's better to keep them in same resource group.

Even after when you decide to split your resources among different resources group you can still do it.
Here's more detailed article about it:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-move-resources/